# Composer - what difference makes using alias in dependency

Tags: composer-php

In my `composer.json` file, I have defined a dependency with an alias:

```
 "require": {
    "xxx/yyy" : "dev-branch as 1.2.3",
    ...
 }
```

This dependency coresponds to a dependeny in another dependent package, which requires as well `"xxx/yyy": "dev-branch as 1.2.3"`

`composer update` rushes through and does not complain.

However, when I change the dependency in my project to

```
 "require": {
    "xxx/yyy" : ">=1.2.3",
    ...
 }
```

composer complains with the error message `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages`. I do not understand. To my comprehension, composer should load the latest version of `dev-branch` and treat it as if it would be version "1.2.3". It doesn't. Why?

Comment: Aliasing in this way is root-only feature, you should not define constraints in this way in dependencies. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#require-inline-alias

Comment: "Complains" sounds weired. Can you share the full and exact error message?

Comment: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`

Comment: the link solved the issue b.t.w.